# Warning: “continue” targeting switch is equivalent to “break”. Errors

Tags: wordpress, warnings

- Question:

Warning: “continue” targeting switch is equivalent to "break". Did you mean to use "continue 2"? in E:\XAMPP\htdocs\wordpress\portfolio-one\wp-content\themes\Divi\includes\builder\functions.php on line 6230

- Answer:

  Go to the folder like example this **:XAMPP\htdocs\wordpress\portfolio-one\wp-content\themes\Divi\includes\builder**
  and then find the **function.php** file and open it by any **code editor like notepad++** and then see your website header which line mentioned and my line is 6230. In 6230 line you will find **"continue"** you just rewrite it **"continue 2"**.

**Save it.**

Answer (score 0):

You need to upgrade your XAMPP software version to 7.3.0 or higher

Comment: already running php version 8.2 xampp till date., not solved this issue